# ArcGIS Pro new project on network drive

Tags: arcgis-pro

I'm currently running on a VPN for work from home and I have access to several network drives.  I'm trying to create a new ArcGIS Pro project on one of the network drives and it seems to hang the software (spins and spins and never opens resulting in a task manager visit).  It works fine if I save my project to the local drives but not the network drives.  I  have full access to the network drives (read and write) and know issues working with files there.

Any thoughts on why this might be a problem.  Again it's not slow it just doesn't work...

Comment: my solution is not going to help you but we VPN>Remote Desktop to office workstations this works much better than straight VPN with ArcGIS Pro (indexing is on by default which is a major bottleneck) https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/projects/index-project-items.htm

Comment: I have similar performance issues with ArcPro over our university VPN. I've abandon all that in favour of putting the project onto Microsoft OneDrive which has the nifty option of only downloading files which you access whilst keeping the rest up on the "cloud".